# Removing a node from Binary Search Tree (BTS), and successor method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, remove-method

In my new class assignment, one of the classes in my program I have to write is a BinarySearchTree class. There are 2 methods on which I am struggling a bit, and that's the `remove` method and `successor` method.

The binary search tree only stores data in the internal nodes, so the leaf nodes are empty, but not null. however in my `remove` method I always get an `nullPointerException` at `if(parent.getLeft() == nodeToBeRemoved)` and I am not sure why.

Here is my code for `remove` method:

```
public void remove(Pair k) throws DictionaryException {
    BinaryNode nodeToBeRemoved = searchTreeNode(root, k); //Searches the tree for the node to be removed.
    if(nodeToBeRemoved.isLeaf()) { //If the search returns a leaf node, the node to be removed is not in the tree.
        throw new DictionaryException("key");
    } else {
        //If the node to be removed has one child (plus one leaf child) or both children are leaf nodes.
        if(nodeToBeRemoved.getLeft().isLeaf() || nodeToBeRemoved.getRight().isLeaf()) {
            BinaryNode childNode;
            if(nodeToBeRemoved.getLeft().isLeaf()) {
                childNode = nodeToBeRemoved.getRight();
            } else {
                childNode = nodeToBeRemoved.getLeft();
            }
            BinaryNode parent = nodeToBeRemoved.getParent(); //Parent of the node to be removed.
            if(nodeToBeRemoved == root) { //If the node to be removed is the root, the child is set to be the new root.
                root = childNode;
            } else {
                if(parent.getLeft() == nodeToBeRemoved) {
                    parent.setLeft(childNode);
                } else {
                    parent.setRight(childNode);
                }
            }
        } else { //If the node to be removed has two children (non leaf children).
            BinaryNode successorNode = smallestNode(nodeToBeRemoved.getRight()); //Finds the successor node of the node to be removed.
            nodeToBeRemoved.setData(successorNode.getData()); //Sets the node to be removed data to be the successor node's data.
            remove(successorNode.getData().getKey()); //The successor is then removed.
        }
    }
}
```

and my `put` method, in case it's actually something wrong with that:

```
public void put(Record r) throws DictionaryException {
    BinaryNode newNode = searchTreeNode(root, r.getKey()); //Searches the tree for the node.
    if(!newNode.isLeaf()) { //If the node is not a leaf, then the data is already in the tree, so exception is thrown.
        throw new DictionaryException("key");
    } else { //Otherwise, the data item is not in the tree, and will be added.
        newNode.setData(r);
        newNode.setLeft(new BinaryNode()); //Sets the left child to be a leaf node.
        newNode.setRight(new BinaryNode()); //Sets the right child to be a leaf node.
    }
}
```

The successor method takes in key "k" and returns the data stored in the successor node, however the key "k" does not have to be stored in any of the node in the tree already, so what I did was temporarily added it to the tree, found the successor node and then removed it using the `remove` method. However, using the test.java file I received from the prof, this method fails the test. Here is my successor code:

```
public Record successor(Pair k) {
    boolean added = false; //A boolean variable to determine if the key is added to the tree.
    BinaryNode tempNode = root;
    //If the key is not in any of the nodes in the tree, then add this node to the tree.
    if(searchTreeNode(tempNode, k).isLeaf()) {
        put(new Record(k, null));
        added = true; //sets added to true, showing that the node with "key" was added.
    }
    BinaryNode inputNode = searchTreeNode(tempNode, k);
    //If the right child of the node is not null, then the successor is the smallest node in the right subtree.
    if(!inputNode.getRight().isLeaf()) {
        return smallestNode(inputNode.getRight()).getData();
    }
    //Otherwise, we have to search up the tree until the parent of the node is the left child of another node. then
    //That "another node" will be the first right ancestor, which is the successor node.
    BinaryNode inputNodeParent = inputNode.getParent();
    while(inputNodeParent != null && inputNode == inputNodeParent.getRight()) {
        inputNode = inputNodeParent;
        inputNodeParent = inputNodeParent.getParent();
    }

    Record dataValue = inputNodeParent.getData();

    //If the key is added to the tree, we need to remove it now, since it was not originally in the tree.
    if(added == true) {
        remove(k);
        added = false;
    }

    return dataValue;
}
```

And the `searchTreeNode` method used in `put` and `remove`:

```
private BinaryNode searchTreeNode(BinaryNode r, Pair k) {
    BinaryNode tempNode = r; //duplicates the root node.
    BinaryNode prev = r.getParent();
    if(tempNode.isLeaf()) {
        return tempNode;
    } else {
        if(tempNode.getData().getKey().compareTo(k) == 0) {
            return tempNode;
        } else if(tempNode.getData().getKey().compareTo(k) == 1) {
            return searchTreeNode(tempNode.getLeft(), k);
        } else {
            return searchTreeNode(tempNode.getRight(), k);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know why I get the `nullPointerException` error in the `remove` method and not really sure why `successor` method fails either.

### Edit

Code for `BinaryNode` `getParent` method along with the constructor:

```
public BinaryNode(Record value, BinaryNode left, BinaryNode right, BinaryNode parent) {
    recordValue = value; //Initializes the Record object.
    leftNode = left; //Initializes the left child of this node.
    rightNode = right; //Initializes the right child of this node.
    parentNode = parent; //Initializes the parent of this node.
}
public BinaryNode() {
    //Initializes all the variable to null.
    recordValue = null;
    leftNode = null;
    rightNode = null;
    parentNode = null;
}
public BinaryNode getParent() {
    return parentNode;
}
```

Comment: The code for `BinaryNode.getParent()` would be of interest, too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have added the code for `getParent` and the constructors for the `BinaryNode` class at the end of the original post, hope it helps answering my question!

Comment: Do `BinaryNode.setLeft(node)` and `setRight(node)` correctly set the `node.parentNode`?

Comment: Those only set the left and right child. Is that the problem? So I should put the `setParent` method with in `BinaryNode.setLeft` and `BinaryNode.setRight` method?

Comment: Probably. If you look at `put()` there is `newNode.setLeft(new BinaryNode());` where you create a new leaf node whose parent isn't set (same for `setRight`).

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will try adding the `setParent` method right now :)

Comment: @MichaelButscher Oh my god, I added the `setParent` method to the code and everything works instantly! Thank you so much for your answer, I feel dumb not adding that in to be honest, it should have been obvious that after setting the child, the parent of the child has to be set too. Gonna keep that in my notes  xD
Thank you again!  :)